# Ionic Collection Repeat - Miss to be populate by websql database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have some troubles with ionic collection repeat. I can't display a populated list from web sql database.
My controller looks like:

```js
.controller('femmeListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dataFemme = [];
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM datafemme', [], function(tx, results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                $scope.dataFemme[i] = {
                    id: results.rows.item(i).id
                    , 'code_patient': results.rows.item(i).code_patient
                };
            }
        });
    });
})
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <a class="item my-item"
     collection-repeat="item in dataFemme | filter:filter"
     collection-item-height="90"
     collection-item-width="'100%'">
    <h2>{{ item.code_patient }}</h2>

  </a>
</div>
```

Please, help.

Comment: try change this results.rows.item(i) to results.rows.item[i]

Comment: Thank you but results.rows.item[i] cannot read properties id or code_patient but results.rows.item(i) can. It seems that the $scope.dataFemme[] or the view is not populated when tx.executeSql select is executed. I thought this $scope.dataFemme[i] = {
                    id: results.rows.item(i).id
                    , 'code_patient': results.rows.item(i).code_patient
                }; cannot be sent outside the tx.executeSql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Angular doesnt know that the variables have changed. Just add a $timeout at the end of the for loop.

**EDITED:**

```
.factory('femmeService', function($q) {
    var femmeService = {};

    femmeService.dataFemme = [];

    femmeService.getAll = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM datafemme', [], function(tx, results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    femmeService.dataFemme[results.rows.item(i).id] = {
                        'id': results.rows.item(i).id,
                        'code_patient': results.rows.item(i).code_patient
                    };
                }
                deferred.resolve();
            });
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return femmeService;
});
```

Then in the controller:

```
femmeService.getAll().then(function() {
    $scope.dataFemme = femmeService.dataFemme;
});
```

Comment: Please can you give me a sample code? I don't know how to do that currently

Comment: deferred.resolve(femmeService);

    femmeService.getAll().then(function(response) {
    $scope.dataFemme = response.dataFemme;
});

I believe this should be the syntax @leandro-zubrezki

Comment: To dont need to return the data in the function because is saved in the factory object, is just to know when it finished.

Comment: Amazing, the collection-repeat is now populated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code like that :
I created the new service below

```
.factory('femmeService', function($timeout) {
var dataFemme = [];
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM datafemme', [], function(tx, results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            //dataFemme[results.rows.item(i).id] = {
            dataFemme[i] = {
                id: results.rows.item(i).id
                , 'code_patient': results.rows.item(i).code_patient
            };
        }
        $timeout(function() {
            dataFemme;
        }, 3000);
    });
});
return {
    all: function() {
        return dataFemme;
    },
    get: function(id) {

        return dataFemme[id];
    }
};})
```

And also changed the controller

```
.controller('femmeListCtrl', function($scope, femmeService) {
$scope.dataFemme = femmeService.all();})
```

And I have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Leandro Zubreski, after using $timeout in the service, the mistake was the index of dataFemme[results.rows.item(i).id] so I used this

```
dataFemme[i] = {
            id: results.rows.item(i).id
            , 'code_patient': results.rows.item(i).code_patient
        };
```

and everything gone right.

Comment: Perfect!, but the problem at the beginning was other (if you have angular inside a non angular function the scope.apply is never called and the scope is never updated. I just put a sample code, you have to check for errors and reject the promise in that case.